# Regular Expression that matches any string of characters up to "/" Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have a Javascript function that loops through href navigation and matches it to the url location. If the two match then an "active" class is added. This works great, except for when someone goes to a page like "services/service1". How would I add the logic to look a string like "services/service1" or "blog/post1" and trim to just "services/" and "blog/"?

Here is my current function

```
scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, current, previous) {
        var location       = current.$$route.originalPath;
        var selectionhref  = element.children().find('a');
        //Searches for match of routepath url and href, removes siblings active, adds active
        (function(){ 
          element.children().each(function(index){
          console.log(location);  
          if($(selectionhref[index]).attr('href') == location){
          $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');  
           $(this).addClass('active');
          };
          });
        })()
      }); //routeChangeSuccess
```

Comment: `location.split('/').shift() + '/'`

Comment: Another option using a similar technique to just drop the last part of the `/`: `location.split('/').reverse().slice(1).reverse().join('/')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way without an RE or `Split`;

```
var root = location.substr(0, (location + "/").indexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace` function. It accepts a variety of params, one being a regular expression and the replacement string.

```
> "services/service1".replace(/[^\/]+$/, "")
'services/'
```

`[^\/]+` matches any character but not a forward slash `/` one or more times. `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hW9fI7/4)